# How can I plot the evolution of two variables over a time range? Add the yearly median ideal point of the two varibles

Tags: r

One problem with using the proportion of votes that agree with the United States or Russia as a measure of state preferences is that the ideological positions, and consequently the voting patterns, of the two countries, might themselves have changed over time. This makes it difficult to know which countries’ ideological positions have changed. Investigate this issue by plotting the evolution of the two countries' ideal points over time. Add the yearly median ideal point of all countries. How might the results of this analysis modify (or not) your interpretation of the previous analysis?

Data available in 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/unvoting.csv'

This is what I was able to do so far:

```
unvotes<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/unvoting.csv")
  data<- filter(unvotes, Year==2012)
    data$CountryAbb<-NULL
```

Comment: Hi Gabriela, I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61763329/13095326) recently. I wonder if you two are in the same class. Also, your teacher is clearly uploading datasets from all over the internet to his GitHub without attribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
UNvotes <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/unvoting.csv")

str(UNvotes)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- filter(UNvotes, CountryAbb %in% c('RUS','USA'))

Median <- group_by(UNvotes, Year) %>%
  summarise(m=median(idealpoint))

ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=idealpoint, col=CountryName)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data=Median, aes(y=m), col="blue", lty=2) +
  labs(caption = "Comparison of idealogical positions for USA and Russia.
                  \nBlue dotted line indicates yearly median of all countries") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom", 
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face="italic"))
```

---

[image]